Linux Mint LMDE - Cortex XDR not working correctly
I have fresh install of Linux Mint LMDE 6.
I've installed Cortex XDR (v8.2.1.120305) but only one service is running, other services are stopped:
$|>> sudo /opt/traps/bin/cytool runtime query
              Name       PID           User                Status               Command
               pmd      1056           root               Running               /opt/traps/bin/pmd
              clad       N/A            N/A               STOPPED               N/A
              dypd       N/A            N/A               STOPPED               N/A
              spmd       N/A            N/A               STOPPED               N/A
              lted       N/A            N/A               STOPPED               N/A
              pyxd       N/A            N/A               STOPPED               N/A


I've tried to stop them all and then start them manually but it didn't work, only one service started:
$|>> sudo /opt/traps/bin/cytool runtime stop all
              Name       PID           User                Status               Command
               pmd       N/A            N/A               STOPPED               N/A
              clad       N/A            N/A               STOPPED               N/A
              dypd       N/A            N/A               STOPPED               N/A
              spmd       N/A            N/A               STOPPED               N/A
              lted       N/A            N/A               STOPPED               N/A
              pyxd       N/A            N/A               STOPPED               N/A

$|>> sudo /opt/traps/bin/cytool runtime start all
              Name       PID           User                Status               Command
               pmd    229201           root               Running               /opt/traps/bin/pmd
              clad       N/A            N/A               STOPPED               N/A
              dypd       N/A            N/A               STOPPED               N/A
              spmd       N/A            N/A               STOPPED               N/A
              lted       N/A            N/A               STOPPED               N/A
              pyxd       N/A            N/A               STOPPED               N/A


I've found one workaround but it's for Linux Mint and didn't work on my system.
Did someone have similar problem?
Can someone help with this?

I've found solution; for some reason dypd service hasn't been started which in turn starts other services.
Solution is following:
check if proxy is enabled/disabled
$ sudo /opt/traps/bin/cytool proxy query
Cloud Defined Proxy settings:
-----------------------------
Status:                        Disabled
Proxy HTTP timeout:
  Actual: 10000ms
  Policy: 10000ms
  By Policy: Yes

set and enable proxy
$ sudo /opt/traps/bin/cytool proxy set "192.168.168.168:8888"                                                                                           
Setting Cloud Defined proxy list to: 192.168.168.168:8888 completed successfully.

$ sudo /opt/traps/bin/cytool proxy query
Cloud Defined Proxy settings:
-----------------------------
Status:                        Enabled
Proxy HTTP timeout:
  Actual: 10000ms
  Policy: 10000ms
  By Policy: Yes

Defined proxy list:
  192.168.168.168:8888
Last good proxy:

start dypd service
 $ sudo /opt/traps/bin/dypd

check if all services are running 
$ sudo /opt/traps/bin/cytool runtime query
              Name       PID           User                Status               Command
               pmd      1092           root               Running               /opt/traps/bin/pmd
              clad      1716       cortexu+               Running               /opt/traps/analyzerd/clad
              dypd      1707           root               Running               /opt/traps/bin/dypdng
              spmd      1732       cortexu+               Running               /opt/traps/analyzerd/spmd
              lted      1862       cortexu+               Running               /opt/traps/python/payload/lted
              pyxd      1288           root               Running               /opt/traps/python/payload/pyxd 


